# Error `executable aws not found` with kubectl config defined by `aws eks update-kubeconfig`

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-eks, kubeconfig

I defined my KUBECONFIG for the AWS EKS cluster:

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --region eu-west-1 --name yb-demo
```

but got the following error when using `kubectl`:

```
...
Use "kubectl <command> --help" for more information about a given command.
Use "kubectl options" for a list of global command-line options (applies to all commands).
[opc@C eks]$ kubectl get sc
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable aws not found

It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.

To learn more about this feature, consult the documentation available at:
      https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in `~/.kube/config` the `command: aws` doesn't use the PATH environment and doesn't find it. Here is how to change it to the full path:

```
sed -e "/command: aws/s?aws?$(which aws)?" -i ~/.kube/config
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also append your custom aws cli installation path to the $PATH variable in `~/.bash_profile`: `export PATH=$PATH:<path to aws cli program directory>`. This way you do not need to `sed` the kubeconfig file every time you add an EKS cluster. Also you will be able to use `aws` command at the command prompt without specifying full path to the program for every execution.

Comment: Right, I realized later that I had it in the PATH with ~ for the home directory. Works in bash but not here

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when installing kubectx on Ubuntu Linux via a Snap package. It does not seem to be able to access the AWS CLI then. I worked around the issue by removing the Snap package and just using the shell scripts instead.